# Changing option inputs with different checkbox choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox

I have three choices that I am specifically using checkboxes for, Bronze, Silver, and Gold. When someone clicks on one of the checkbox options, I am wanting the results in the select to be different, based on the options in the appropriate if statement. Then once that person chooses and option to be able to send the value to the html.

Right now, I am only getting  the `#top-bronze:checked` options appearing, no matter which option I check. However, this isn't showing in the snippet for some reason.

Does anyone see what I need to do to be able to get the correct options to show based on the checked results?

```js
    function tpYears() {

      if ('#tp-bronze:checked') {
        $("#tp-frequency").html("<option value=''disabled selected>Please choose option</option><option value='3'>3 years - 3 cards</option><option value='4'>2 years - 4 cards</option><option value='2'>5 years - 2 cards</option>");
      } else if ('#tp-silver:checked') {
        $("#tp-frequency").html("<option value=''disabled selected>Please choose option</option><option value='5'>3 years - 5 cards</option><option value='3'>5 years - 3 cards</option><option value='2'>7 years - 2 cards</option>");
      } else if ('#tp-gold:checked') {
        $("#tp-frequency").html("<option value=''disabled selected>Please choose option</option><option value='7'>3 years - 7 cards</option><option value='4'>5 years - 4 cards</option><option value='3'>7 years - 3 cards</option>");
      }
      var templates = $('#tp-frequency option:selected');
    };
    tpYears();
```

```html
<label for="tp-bronze" class="package-check-toggle tp-package-push">Bronze
</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" id="tp-bronze" value="Bronze Touch Point Package">
<label for="tp-silver" class="package-check-toggle tp-package-push">Silver
</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" id="tp-silver" value="Silver Touch Point Package">
<label for="tp-gold" class="package-check-toggle tp-package-push">Gold
</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" id="tp-gold" value="Gold Touch Point Package">
```

Comment: Your if statement string isn't wrapped in $()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the condition within the if-else with `$()`. You can also use prop to check the `checked` status of checkbox like the blow `first` and `second` condition

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        if ($('#tp-bronze').prop('checked')) {
        $("#tp-frequency").html("<option value=''disabled selected>Please choose option</option><option value='3'>3 years - 3 cards</option><option value='4'>2 years - 4 cards</option><option value='2'>5 years - 2 cards</option>");
      } else if ($('#tp-silver').prop('checked')) {
        $("#tp-frequency").html("<option value=''disabled selected>Please choose option</option><option value='5'>3 years - 5 cards</option><option value='3'>5 years - 3 cards</option><option value='2'>7 years - 2 cards</option>");
      } else if ($('#tp-gold:checked')) {
        $("#tp-frequency").html("<option value=''disabled selected>Please choose option</option><option value='7'>3 years - 7 cards</option><option value='4'>5 years - 4 cards</option><option value='3'>7 years - 3 cards</option>");
      }
      var templates = $('#tp-frequency option:selected');
    
  
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="tp-bronze" class="package-check-toggle tp-package-push">Bronze
</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" id="tp-bronze" value="Bronze Touch Point Package">
<label for="tp-silver" class="package-check-toggle tp-package-push">Silver
</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" id="tp-silver" value="Silver Touch Point Package">
<label for="tp-gold" class="package-check-toggle tp-package-push">Gold
</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" id="tp-gold" value="Gold Touch Point Package">
<select id="tp-frequency"></select>
```

Comment: This results in nothing displaying in my select box and in your snippet it displays the same selection for anything checked?

Comment: Corrected it, that was because the function tpYears was called only once, you need to execute on that on change of checkbox state. However now what happens is that when two checkboxes are checked the one with lower value get prority, but you can always change the logic as you need.

Comment: I am confused why I cannot run my function name?

Comment: you can do it, provided you set an onchange="tpYears()" on each of the checkbox. but if you are anyways using jquery, you can do as I have done in the snippet

Comment: Disregard my last comment.

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Comment: Any idea why I get object object for trying to write the result of the selection? https://jsfiddle.net/rnqpsvr2/

Comment: yeah, because template is a query object of here `var templates = $('#tp-frequency option:selected');`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rnqpsvr2/1/. Handle it like this. Ideally it should have been a different question but its ok. :)

Comment: One more thing if you are using jquery, then you can use it completely, don't mix javascript and jquery, not that its wrong but its not required

Comment: How would I get the value of the options to display though? .... Are you referring to useing `.html()` instead?

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to get the value. I just did this ... `var templates = $('#tp-frequency option:selected').val();` ... I appreciate all the help.